# ¿Cómo sobrescribir una clase de configuración durante un test en spring boot?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, mockito, junit-5

Estoy tratando de desarrollar una prueba de un proyecto en spring boot con Junit + Mockito. Pero tengo un inconveniente al tratar de sobrescribir la configuración. Dentro de la clase de configuración se aloja un Bean de un cliente de Amazon S3 como se muestra a continuación.

```
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration

public class AmazonConfig {

 

  @Bean

  public AmazonS3 s3() {

      AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();

     return s3;

  }
```

Dentro de la prueba se tiene el siguiente código para inyectar el bean.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)

@ActiveProfiles("test")

@Import(AmazonTestConfiguration.class)

public class Tests {

 

    @Autowired

    private AmazonS3 s3;

 

    public ComplaintResponse myTest1() {

        // logic here

    }

}
```

Además se definió una clase que contiene el mockeo del cliente Amazon S3.

```
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@TestConfiguration
public class AmazonTestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public AmazonS3 s3() {
            return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                    .standard()
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(http://localhost:5000, "us-west-2"))
                    .build();
    }
}
```

lo que sucede es que al momento de correr la prueba se esta instanciando el Bean de AmazonConfig y  no esta tomando el que quiero sobrescribir que contiene unas credenciales personalizadas de un un mock de aws S3 en docker

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint:

    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.getToken(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:91) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:69) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:403) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:372) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:368) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getEC2InstanceRegion(EC2MetadataUtils.java:283) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.regions.InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.tryDetectRegion(InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.java:59) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.regions.InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.getRegion(InstanceMetadataRegionProvider.java:50) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.regions.AwsRegionProviderChain.getRegion(AwsRegionProviderChain.java:46) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.determineRegionFromRegionProvider(AwsClientBuilder.java:475) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:458) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:424) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:54) [aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.test.config.AmazonConfig.s3(AmazonConfig.java:13) [classes/:na]

    at com.test.config.AmazonConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6934bcfa.CGLIB$s3$0(<generated>) [classes/:na]

    at com.test.config.AmazonConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6934bcfa$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$488781bf.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:na]

    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) [spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) [spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at com.test.config.AmazonConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6934bcfa.s3(<generated>) [classes/:na]

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]

    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:448) ~[spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]

    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]

    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136) ~[spring-boot-test-2.5.12.jar:2.5.12]

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]

    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]

    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]

    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]

    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]

    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]

    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]

    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]

    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect

    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1199) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984) ~[na:1.8.0_202]

    at com.amazonaws.internal.ConnectionUtils.connectToEndpoint(ConnectionUtils.java:52) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:80) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.1.jar:na]

    ... 156 common frames omitted
```

PD: Vale la pena mencionar que hacemos uso de localstack para emular la conexión al s3.

Muchas gracias por la atención prestada .

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Te faltó indicarnos cuál es tu problema con este código. Puedes ir a [edit] y aclararlo

Comment: se actualiza post

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizando la anotación `@ContextConfiguration` en lugar de `@Import`.

Te dejo un enlace [acá](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-import-annotation) donde describe el uso que se le suele dar a `@Import`